# How to calculate the sum of EditText boxes?

Tags: android, textview, calculator

Hi all I am having a little trouble handling this question. I have 5 EditText boxes and I ask the user to put a number in them. Then I want to calculate the sum of the EditText boxes and do something with the sum. However I am having trouble in the case if the user don't put a number in all the boxes.

Is it possible to put a default value "0" in the boxes just in case not all the boxes are filled but the sum to be calculated although not all the boxes are filled?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_extra_question);       

    textBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    textBox3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    textBox4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    textBox5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    buttON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    buttON.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {               
            number1 = Integer.parseInt(textBox1.getText().toString());
            number2 = Integer.parseInt(textBox2.getText().toString());
            number3 = Integer.parseInt(textBox3.getText().toString());
            number4 = Integer.parseInt(textBox4.getText().toString());
            number5 = Integer.parseInt(textBox5.getText().toString());

            sum = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4 + number5;
            if(sum > 100)
            {                   
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nice!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail!",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this for each number:

```
number1 = textBox1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()?0:Integer.parseInt(textBox1.getText().trim().toString());
```

Comment: I'd suggest trimming whitespace off the text before checking if it is empty: `textBox1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() ? ...`

Comment: y not. Should also trim before parseInt

Comment: I dont think I need trim() since its a number textbox and the user cant use other symbols than numbers

Answer (score 2):

Create on function like this

```
public int getIntFromString(String str) {

    if (str != null) {

        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            return 0;
        } else {

            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(str);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then Your code should be

```
        number1 = getIntFromString(textBox1.getText().toString().trim());
        number2 = getIntFromString(textBox2.getText().toString().trim());
        number3 = getIntFromString(textBox3.getText().toString().trim());
        number4 = getIntFromString(textBox4.getText().toString().trim());
        number5 = getIntFromString(textBox5.getText().toString().trim());
```

Comment: I'd suggest making the function return 0 if a `NumberFormatException` is thrown by `parseInt(str)` (unless you guarantee numeric input only). Also giving a more explicit name to the function based on what it actually does.

Comment: Regarding the name I thought something in the lines of `getIntFromStringOrZero()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes your idea is correct. For each of the edit texts , just check:

```
if(textBox1.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
      number1 = 0;
}
else
    number1 = Integer.parseInt(textBox1.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check Empty String using the below code and put "0" in every missing value.

```
number1 = textBox1.getText().toString().isEmpty()?0:Integer.parseInt(textBox1.getText().toString());
number2 = textBox2.getText().toString().isEmpty()?0:Integer.parseInt(textBox2.getText().toString());
number3 = textBox3.getText().toString().isEmpty()?0:Integer.parseInt(textBox3.getText().toString());
number4 = textBox4.getText().toString().isEmpty()?0:Integer.parseInt(textBox4.getText().toString());
number5 = textBox5.getText().toString().isEmpty()?0:Integer.parseInt(textBox5.getText().toString());
```